# bokeh tabs does not clear for subsequent figure

Tags: bokeh

I'm not sure I can provide enough context here but I think so.

I'm running a bokeh server to generate a few plots and in a Flask app put them on a page, like this

```
script1 = bokeh.embed.server_document(...)
script2 = bokeh.embed.server_document(...)
...
return render_template(..., script1=script1, script2=script2)
```

On the template each plot is wrapped in a div with line breaks, paragraph breaks, and so on:

```
<style>
  .gap-20 {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
   }
</style>

<p>
<h3>Anchors and their inferences</h3>
<br />
<div class="gap-20">
  {{ script1 | safe }}
</div>
</p>

<p>
<h3>Reproduction of forward data</h3>
<br />
<div class="gap-20">
  {{ script2 | safe }}
</div>
</p>
```

The plots that mess up layout on the page are those containing 'Panel' and 'Tabs'. Other plots are fine. See image for the problem.

[image]

The problem is: the plot using 'Tabs' does not **clear**, so that the capture of the next plot, "Reproduction of forward data", appears to the right of the figure on the active tab, just below the tab titles, although I have plenty of 
 and

before "Reproduction of forward data".

The code for 'script1' is like this on the Bokeh server side:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Slider, Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.layouts import column

f1 = figure(...)
s1 = Slider(...)
fig1 = column(s1, f1)
f2 = figure(...)
s2 = Slider(...)
fig2 = column(s2, f2)

tab1 = Panel(child=fig1, ...)
tab2 = Panel(child=fig2, ...)
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2])

doc.add_root(tabs)
```

A puzzling part is that this used to work a few weeks ago, back then 'tabs' is wrapped in 'column', like 'doc.add_root(column(tabs))'. Days ago I upgraded Bokeh to the latest 0.12.13, the issue above appeared. With or without 'column', the issue is the same. I'm not totally sure Bokeh upgrade is the cause but it's very likely so.

So the question is, what needs to be done around this 'Tabs' or 'Panel' to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

New findings: with Bokeh 0.12.10, with `Tabs` wrapped in `row` or `column`, that is,

```
doc.add_root(row(tabs))
```

or

```
doc.add_root(column(tabs))
```

things work as expected. The next plot comes cleanly below the first. If `Tabs` are passed to `doc.add_root` w/o `row` or `column`, the problem described in the post and shown in the picture occurs.

Now upgrade to Bokeh 0.12.11, w/o `row` or `column` around `Tabs`, same problem as shown in the original question post (and the same as with Bokeh 0.12.10). With `row` or `column`, things are messier:

[image]

The two figures seem to be vertically collapsed. This bug continues through the latest version, 0.12.13.